# How to see values of for dynamic segments like Insert Caption instead of their formulas?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, caption

When I insert caption or any formula fields I am seeing like this: `{SEQ Fig. \*ARABIC}` instead of Fig. 1. This is for all the dynamic segments(I do not know the correct terminology) of the word like dynamic index, dynamic page numebers etc. Of course in another system I am seeing the dynamic segments with values instead of formulas. How can I see values and formulas?

Comment: Have you tried to press Alt and F9?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on `{SEQ Fig. \*ARABIC}`, then select Toggle Field Codes. You should be able to see human readable part of the caption.